# How to remove special characters from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking into how to create a program that removes any whitespaces/special characters from user input. I wan't to be left with just a string of numbers but I've not been able to work out quite how to do this. Is it possible anyone can help?

```
x = (input("Enter a debit card number: "))
x.translate(None, '!.;,')
print(x)
```

The code I have created is possibly to basic but yeah, it also doesn't work. Can anyone please help? :) I'm using Python3.

Answer (score 2):

The way `str.translate` works is different in Py 3.x - it requires mapping a dictionary of ordinals to values, so instead you use:

```
x = input("Enter a debit card number: ")
result = x.translate(str.maketrans({ord(ch):None for ch in '!.;,'}))
```

Although you're better off just removing all non digits:

```
import re
result = re.sub('[^0-9], x, '')
```

Or using builtins:

```
result = ''.join(ch for ch in x if ch.isidigit())
```

It's important to note that strings are immutable and their methods return a *new* string - be sure to either assign back to the object or some other object to retain the result.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `translate` for this aim . instead you can use `regex` :

```
import re
x = input("Enter a debit card number: ")
x = re.sub(r'[\s!.;,]*','',x)
```

> [\s!.;,]* match a single character present in the list below:
>
> Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as
> possible, giving back as needed [greedy] \s match any white space
> character [\r\n\t\f ] !.;, a single character in the list !.;,
> literally
>
> [re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
> occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

Comment: I get invalid syntax when using that way

Comment: @JurgenvanVossen try it again , i fix it !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wanted only numbers (credit card number)

```
import re: # or 'from re import sub'

s = re.sub('[^0-9]+', "", my_str);
```

I've used this as an input:
    `my_str = "663388191712-483498-39434347!2848484;290850 2332049832048 23042 2 2";`

What I've got is only numbers (because you mentioned that you want to be left with only numbers):

```
66338819171248349839434347284848429085023320498320482304222
```